# Geometric Interpretation of Projective Cover

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

The projective cover of a module $V$ is defined to be an epimorphism $p\colon P\rightarrow V$ where $P$ is a projective module and $\ker(p)$ is superfluous.
Now I wonder if there is any interpretation (or an analogue) of this notion in terms of algebraic geometry?

Comment: + is there any interpretation of an injective hull geometrically?

Comment: Which category would you be looking for projective covers in? I would assume it would be quasi-coherent sheaves, but in general this category does not have enough projectives, let alone projective covers.